# How to link thumbnail image to a large image

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, gallery

I'm trying to create a simple image gallery that displays thumbnails of uploaded images. Once a thumbnail is clicked, I would like to be directed to a page with the large version of the image, along with a comment section. So basically I'm trying to do something similar to deviantart. What I have now looks something like this:

`<a href="<?php echo $image->large_image_path; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $image->thumbnail_image_path; ?>"></a>`

Clicking on a thumbnail will take to me to the large image path, which is not really what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $image->large_image_page; ?>"> Seriously, this is beyond the scope of SO, its about the entire design of your site. SO if about specific problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make the `href="<?php echo $image->large_image_path; ?>"` to somehing like `href="show_image.php?image_path=<?php echo $image->large_image_path; ?>"`

In show_image.php you can den get the path of the image by `$_REQUEST['image_path']`, and add it into the code like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_REQUEST['image_path']; ?> />
```

The you can add information or styling around the bigger image.

So, link to a PHP page instead of the image. Even better, put the image path in to a database, and use the image id to get the path and information of the image. Like this:

`href="show_image.php?image_id=<?php echo $image->id; ?>">` and then in show_image.php, given that you have a method for getting the image:

```
<?php $image = GetImage($_REQUEST['image_id']); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image->large_image_path; ?> />
<?php echo $image->description; ?> 
<?php echo $image->date; ?>
```

Hope this helps you on the way.